# how can i manually edit a web deploy package?

Tags: asp.net, windows, msbuild, webdeploy

I generate a package like this:

```
msbuild myapp.csproj /T:Package
```

I want to transform the package after it has been created.

I dont want to use parameters.xml because i already have a bunch of xdt transforms and using another totally difference transform tool for the same thing is really stupid.

I can script opening the zip, applying my xdt transforms, then zipping it back up

But deploying that package, Web deploy deleted the entire site directory and failed.

Why? Does webdeploy hash the files or something making it impossible to manually edit a package after it has been created (outside of the parameters.xml thing)? After generating a package if I go into the zip and edit web.config or any other configs the modified package cant be deployed

The error was:

```
ERROR: msdeploy failed : SetParameters from:
"C:\...\...\package.SetParameters.xml"
```